# How to bind keyboard layout in opengl game?

Tags: games, keyboard-layout

How to bind in-game actions to hardware keys not to layout variables? Keys stops working when I randomly change them in game (Quake Live or Quake III) by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Comment: what game is this?

Comment: quake live or quake 3..

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to bind directly to the xinput keys, unless I misunderstand your question. Is there a situation where binding to the quake 3 keys is insufficient?

Can you provide a concrete example of what you want to do, step by step?