# Is 12.04 compatible with the Dell XPS 14Z laptop?

Tags: 12.04, installation, 64-bit, laptop, dell

Thinking of buying above Ultrabook and installing Ubuntu. Anyone done this already?

Comment: PC mag. review: http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2395124,00.asp

Comment: I tried running 12.04 64bit from a USB key and it all worked flawlessly. I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Dell XPS 14z (L412z) running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and, in general, I'm very satisfied. It's a great machine but some issues need to be solved after installing Ubuntu 12.04.

I've made a thread in Ubuntu Forums about how to [solve temperature, battery and touchpad issues](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2127448).

Here it is:

## Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Dell XPS 14z - temperature, touchpad and other issues

Here are solutions and workarounds that I found for temperature and battery consumption on the Dell XPS 14z (L412z) notebook, while running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin).

### TEMPERATURE ISSUE AND BATTERY LIFE ON DELL XPS 14Z WITH UBUNTU 12.04 LTS

After these tweaks, the CPU temperature will run in about 40 up to 48ºC with regular use (this is OK), and up to 80ºC when gaming (my alarm is set to 85ºC). The HDD temperature will decrease to 36 up to 41ºC.

#### 1. Install and configure lm-sensors and cpufrequtils:

```
    sudo apt-get install lm-sensors cpufrequtils indicator-cpufreq
    sudo sensors-detect
```

(confirm all options with "y")

#### 2. Install Psensor to keep track of your CPU and HD temperature:

```
    sudo apt-get install psensor
```

(choose to activate "hddtemp" on boot when asked)

- After install it will execute automaticaly on system startup.
- You can block it on the launcher to see it permanently (the launcher icon has a neat temperature indicator).

#### 3. Install Jupiter to manage battery consumption:

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter && sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

#### 4. Install Bumblebee to manage battery consumption and the use of the nVIDIA GPU when needed (use "optirun" before the application name to open with nVIDIA GPU):

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable && sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install bumblebee
```

- Test and compare:

  ```
  glxspheres
  optirun glxspheres
  ```

#### 5. To decrease Hard Disk temperature (the unconfortable heating on your left palm hand, where the HDD hardware is set), you will have to install laptop-mode-tools and follow the instructions on the link below:

```
    sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
```

- Edit laptop-mode.conf file:

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/laptop-mode/laptop-mode.conf
  ```
- Find the bellow text and change value to 600:

  ```
  NOLM_HD_IDLE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS=7200
  ```
- Find the bellow texts and change both values to 1:

  ```
  LM_AC_HD_POWERMGMT=254
  NOLM_AC_HD_POWERMGMT=254
  ```
- Refers to:
  http://askubuntu.com/questions/14134...ng-on-ac-power

#### 6. Use Powertop (from Intel) software to tweak some power consumption settings:

```
    sudo apt-get install powertop
    sudo powertop --calibrate
```

(wait)

```
    sudo powertop
```

(change "Bad" values to "Good" using keyboard arrows and 'Enter'. Type 'Esc' when finished.) -- this is not 100% tested.

#### 7. Those above are the easiest tips that I've found. To go more deep, you can refer the links bellow and, later, post here what you accomplished:

http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.c...in-ubuntu.html

### TOUCHPAD SENSIBILITY ISSUE ON DELL XPS 14Z WITH UBUNTU 12.04 LTS

The mouse pointer keeps shaking and jumping on the screen when I use touchpad on my Dell XPS 14z, especially in cold rooms. It's horrible! These are some tweaks that I tryied with the synclient software, that manages the Synaptics driver (responsible for touchpad in Ubuntu 12.04). Try some of those an let me know if it worked for you.

#### 1. Ultimately, I've had success by changing the HorizHysteresis and VertHysteresis values on the synclient for 48. Do this:

- Check the current value (should be 8):

  ```
  synclient | grep HorizHysteresis && synclient | grep VertHysteresis
  ```
- Change value to 72 on each (first I tried 48, with goog results also):

  ```
  synclient HorizHysteresis=72 && synclient VertHysteresis=72
  ```
- These tweaks will be lost after system restart. To make the changes permanent, you'll have to create and edit a xorg.conf file. Do this:

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
  ```
- It will open a blank text file. Insert the following content and save:

  ```
  Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "Touchpad"
  Driver "synaptics"
  MatchIsTouchpad "on"
  Option "VertHysteresis" "72"
  Option "HorizHysteresis" "72"
  EndSection
  ```
- For more options on xorg.conf file, refer to:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/13021...xorg-conf-file and
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php...y_used_options

#### 2. Other tweaks that I've tried before (with less success) was changing the FingerLow, FingerHigh and FingerPress values with the above commands:

- First, check the FingerLow, FingerHigh and FingerPress current values with the above command:

  ```
  synclient | grep FingerLow && synclient | grep FingerHigh && synclient | grep FingerPress
  ```
- You will probably get:

  ```
  FingerLow = 25
  FingerHigh = 30
  FingerPress = 256
  ```
- Try decreasing FingerLow and increasing FingerHigh values (I actually didn't try to change FingerPress values becouse the HorizHysteresis and VertHysteresis tweaking showed to be the better solution). To change any value, do such as:

  ```
  synclient FingerLow=20
  synclient FingerHigh=50
  ```

Refer to:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/12802...sitivity-issue

For more settings on Synaptics driver, refer to:
http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc...naptics.4.html

#### 3. Enable two fingers scrolling in System Settings > Mouse and Touchpad > Touchpad (this is optional)

### OTHER THINGS THAT I DO AFTER INSTALLING UBUNTU 12.04 LTS ON MY DELL XPS 14Z

This is my personal check-list, but it has some cool tips.

#### 1. Install Java (necessary for internet banking):

```
    sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre icedtea-plugin
```

(resolve problema do Banco do Brasil no Ubuntu / funciona para o Mozilla Firefox) -- this is a tip for my brazilian fellows.

#### 2. Install ubuntu restricted extras package:

```
    sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

#### 3. Show global menu in LibreOffice:

```
    sudo apt-get install lo-menubar
```

#### 4. Improve clipboard (copy and paste between apps even after closing the previous one):

```
    sudo apt-get install parcellite
```

- To make it run on system startup, go to settings (cog in the top right of your desktop screen in Unity) and click on Startup Applications. Then click 'Add' and write "parcellite" on the two first fiels. Confirm.

#### 5. Reduce font size, Launcher appearence and put a Show Desktop Icon on the Launcher:

```
    sudo apt-get install myunity
```

- On Font, set font sizes -1 of the current.
- On Launcher, set Backlights as 'Active Icons Only'.
- On Desktop, set Active "Show Desktop" icon as ON.

#### 6. Install the best app to backup personal files, usb drives and external drives (FreeFileSync):

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freefilesync/ffs && sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install freefilesync
```

#### 7. Install Radio Tray Indicator (I recomend the "CINEMIX" radio):

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eugenesan/ppa && sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install radiotray
```

- For other great indicators, refere to:
  http://maketecheasier.com/10-must-ha...-04/2012/06/15

#### 8. Creating a keyboard shortcut to open files and directories (Nautilus) - Similar to 'Super + E' on Microsoft Windows:

Go to System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Launchers > click 'Personal Folder' and type 'Ctrl + Alt + A' on your keyboard.

#### 9. Install Storage Device Manager and configure particions to mount on boot:

```
    sudo apt-get install pysdm
```

#### 10. Speed up Ubuntu

- Watch: http://youtu.be/vwBoHZuauL8

#### 11. Disable/remove overlay scrollbars:

```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface ubuntu-overlay-scrollbars false
```

### FULL REFERENCES

http://handytutorial.com/install-fre...-04-using-ppa/
http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/ho...ntu-12-04-lts/
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/thing...ng-ubuntu.html
http://askubuntu.com/questions/14134...ng-on-ac-power
http://askubuntu.com/questions/12802...sitivity-issue
http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc...naptics.4.html
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+s...cs/+bug/992330
http://askubuntu.com/questions/13021...xorg-conf-file
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php...y_used_options
http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.c...in-ubuntu.html
http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.c...in-ubuntu.html

Comment: I've got one too and I'm very happy! With an SSD it became pretty fast, and with i8kutils I can control and see the fans also. Suspend and hibernation work also pretty fine. From time to time I've got to rescan the wifi with this command `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if anyone has tried this particular model, but in general it would seem that Dell laptops work well with ubuntu. There's a list of certified hardware available here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/make/Dell/?page=1&category=Desktop&category=Laptop&category=Netbook

Answer (score 1):

try a live media ( for example live CD or Live USB ), boot from that media and will see if your laptop is compitabled with your machine

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying **Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit)** from LiveCD, before either installing alongside (as dual-boot) or fully replacing the **Windows 7 Home Premium** that Dell provides.

**Note:** With an Intel Core i7-2640M (2.8GHz), 8GB RAM, and 750GB hard drive, this should reasonably be 2-3 times faster at most operations under **Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit)** than as supplied with Windows 7.

**UPDATE**

You can't easily use **Windows 7** configuration to release the 'unused' disk space, although that is the recommended (and safe) method.  The vendor may have also tied up 200-400MB for a recovery partition (for Windows 7).  Windows 7 also does not like to shrink past about 243GB, and complains that something important (like swap file) will be affected.

Suggest approach:

Try installing on Windows 7, as **WUBI** install, to see if this will run on this Laptop.  If this fails, or there is not enough room, move on ..

If you have re-install disks for Windows 7, or the shop/vendor will supply them, the replace the current Windows 7 install with 64bit Ubuntu 12.04.  I would not comment trying dual-boot on only 256GB.  You will want to keep 100GB for 'media files', pictures, etc. and it will get full fast even with Windows 7 only hogging 75GB (the plausible minimum).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Silly question, but will testing everything from LiveCD confirm 100% compatability, ie will then be safe to install Ubuntu (wiping Windows).

Comment: No.  The first stage would be testing Ubuntu using **LiveCD**.  The second would be to install **alongside** Windows 7 in (so called) **dual-boot**.  If after a few weeks you are fully satisfied, then you could replace Windows 7 by another install of **Ubuntu**, overwriting the entire disk.  **But**, there is no particular reason to rush this, as you could still run indefinitely with a smaller (150GB) partition of Windows 7 alongside **Ubuntu**.  You don't have to use it, but you may still needed it for some Windows-only software or data conversion/transfer.

Comment: Thank you David that is very helpfull. I have ordered a new XPS 14Z so will post how I get on. It has a 256GB SSD so what is the smallest partition you would require for Win 7 Home Premium 64 Bit?

Comment: add detail to my answer ..